# Getting error stating Bot should use its own storage

Tags: botframework

While I test my latest Bot skills developed in Azure, I get below error. I didn't get this error for my other bots.
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ServiceError",
    "message": "Bot should use its own storage"
  }
}

How do I prevent my code from using Bot storage.

Regards,
Pradeep

Answer (score 4):

As per the documentation of  [Azure Bot Service 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-state?view=azure-bot-service-3.0), it is mandatory to manage state data. You cannot "prevent" your code from using storage.

Comment: The same bot is working fine with Bot channel created two weeks back in Azure portal. But new channel registered in throwing the error "Bot should use its own storage". Not sure if there is any recent change.

Comment: @Pradeep: There are multiple channels available in Azure where you can deploy your bot. Please let me know which channel(s) are you talking about.

Comment: I am using Webchat. I have created "Bot Channels Registration" in Azure and developed Web Service as Fulfillment API.